Basic Authentication returns message: 'Username cannot be blank' when posting on yii2 Rest API eventhough database has it
In Yii2 , I learned to create a Rest API. I can now post get and update data. I recently added Authentication, my token is accepted but is trying to find useranme auth_key password_hash and email from user table. I am updating my reading_schedule table.
I am currently using postman to test the url create of my Rest API
everything works fine without auth until I recently added a Basic Authentication to my Code.

it now shows this message on Postman even though I added my auth key token to authorization
[
    {
        "field": "username",
        "message": "Username cannot be blank."
    },
    {
        "field": "auth_key",
        "message": "Auth Key cannot be blank."
    },
    {
        "field": "password_hash",
        "message": "Password Hash cannot be blank."
    },
    {
        "field": "email",
        "message": "Email cannot be blank."
    }
]

here is my controller under modules v1
<?php

namespace app\modules\v1\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;
use yii\web\Controller;

/**
 * ReadingSchedule controller for the `v1` module
 */
class ReadingScheduleController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass="app\models\ReadingSchedule";
    
    public function behaviors() //override
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [            
            'class' => \yii\filters\auth\CompositeAuth::class,
            'authMethods' => [
                \yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth::class,
                \yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth::class,                
                [
                    'class' => \yii\filters\auth\CompositeAuth::class,
                ]
            ]             
            
        ];
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => \yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth::class,
            'auth' => [$this, 'auth']
        ];
        return $behaviors;
    }

    public function auth($username, $password)
    {
        return \app\models\User::findOne(['login' => $username, 'password' => $password]);
    }



    
}

Here is my User Module as it stated that I need to implement identity Interface
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "user".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $auth_key
 * @property string|null $verification_token
 * @property string $password_hash
 * @property string|null $password_reset_token
 * @property string $email
 * @property int $status
 * @property string $created_at
 * @property string $updated_at
 */
class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{

    const STATUS_DELETED = 0;
    const STATUS_INACTIVE = 9;
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 10;
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
            ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_INACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'username' => 'Username',
            'auth_key' => 'Auth Key',
            'verification_token' => 'Verification Token',
            'password_hash' => 'Password Hash',
            'password_reset_token' => 'Password Reset Token',
            'email' => 'Email',
            'status' => 'Status',
            'created_at' => 'Created At',
            'updated_at' => 'Updated At',
        ];
    }
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return static::findOne($id);
    }

    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        return static::findOne(['auth_key' => $token]);
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->auth_key;  // Updated case for property name
    }
  
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->auth_key === $authKey;  // Updated case for property name
    }
  }




After Hours of research, I have tried QueryParamAuth as example authentication.
The 422 data validation error messages I've been encountering in Postman with QueryParamAuth likely occur because the code is still trying to validate user data even though I'm using access tokens for authentication. Here's what's happening and how to fix it:
Reason for the Errors:
The actionCreate logic is designed for form-based authentication, where user data is submitted in the request body. It expects fields like username, auth_key, password_hash, and email to be present.
QueryParamAuth sends the access token as a URL parameter, not in the request body.
Solution:
There are two main approaches to address this:
1. Separate Logic for API Requests:
Create a separate action method specifically for handling API requests using QueryParamAuth.
In this new action method, retrieve the access token from the URL parameter (e.g.,
$accessToken = Yii::$app->request->getQueryParam('access_token')).
Validate the access token (e.g., check its validity in your database or use a token validation library).
If the token is valid, proceed with creating the reading schedule without user data validation.
2. Conditional Check in actionCreate (Modified Approach):
Modify your existing actionCreate logic to handle both form submissions and API requests.
Add a check to see if the request method is POST and the access token is present in the URL parameter.
If it's an API request with a valid access token, bypass user data validation and proceed with creating the reading schedule. Otherwise, continue with the form-based validation logic.
Here's the modified actionCreate code using the conditional check approach:
PHP
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new ReadingSchedule();

    $accessToken = Yii::$app->request->getQueryParam('access_token');

    if ($this->request->isPost() && $accessToken) {
        // API request with access token (bypass validation)
        $user = // Retrieve user based on valid access token (implement logic)
        if (!$user) {
            return $this->asJson(['message' => 'Invalid access token'], 401); // Unauthorized
        }

        // ... proceed with creating reading schedule using user object ...

    } else {
        // Regular form submission (validate user data)
        if ($model->load($this->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}

Additional Notes:
Remember to implement the logic for retrieving a user based on the valid access token ($user = // Retrieve user based on valid access token (implement logic)).
Adjust the error handling (e.g., returning a 401 Unauthorized response) based on your specific needs.
By implementing one of these approaches, you should be able to handle both form submissions and API requests with QueryParamAuth in your actionCreate logic. The API request will bypass user data validation and rely on the access token for authentication.
